# When to separate out functions in php OOP

Tags: php, oop

I'm coding an interface class at the moment to manage showing of user comments on two different kinds of pages, one page is the profiles and the other is the media pages.

Both sets of comments are stored in different tables but I'm wondering whether I should use one function or split both tables into a separate function.

Is the overall goal of OOP to have code that works well for your site or to be able to use it over in different sections without the need to modify lots?

I could have:

```
showComments($pageId, $type, $userType)
{
    if($type == 'media')
        $sql = "SELECT comment FROM mediatable WHERE id=:pageId";
    elseif($type == 'profile')
        $sql = "SELECT comment FROM profileTable WHERE id=:pageId";

    if($userType == 'moderator')
        //show Moderation Tools

    //Rest of code goes here
}
```

Or I could seperate it into different functions like so:

```
showMediaComments($id);
moderateMediaComments($id);

showProfileComments($id);
moderateProfileComments($id);
```

I'm thinking the second method would be better as I could then use the code again easier but it would required more lines of code ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither one is proper OOP. A proper way would be to have a abstract Comment class and subclasses MediaComments, ProfileComments that handle the differences. Also, read about the MVC architecture

Comment: Okay I understand the part of different classes and subclasses but what if I wish to split it up and show different versions to guest, member and administrator type users? Would it best to write separate functions for each?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your goal is for your OOP site.
Many people use OOP to different extents and in many different ways, however, if you're using a true MVC, it would have a model class for each database table, so mediatable and profiletable queries wouldn't be in the same function.

That said, in my opinion, separating them would be better. It tends to keep code cleaner and more localized.

Comment: It's not required to have a model class for each table - on the contrary, a model can deal with  multiple tables. It depends on the ORM trough.

Comment: Very true! I use Doctrine for my ORM and Doctrine has a model base class for each table. I've really come to appreciate the way they built their ORM.

Comment: Well I'm creating a basic MVC at the moment and instead of having separate classes for each table it's more for the uses and code to display items are in an interface class. It's my first php OOP project so I'm constantly learning, adapting and changing as I go.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the overall goal of OOP to have code that works well for your site
>   or to be able to use it over in different sections without the need to
>   modify lots?

The overall goal of OOP is to design systems that are more flexible to future changes by providing interfaces and classes which can be optionally extended by future developers to meet needs not originally accounted for.

The goal of modular design (in procedural or OOP code) is to create small chunks of code that represent *each logic bit* which is it's own *independent block* (i.e. function/method). In other words, each logical task should be broken down into the individual components that make it up in the same way you would normalize a database table in a RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the overall goal of OOP to have code that works well for your site

Think about it, OOP or not, you'll always want code that works well for your site :)

> or to be able to use it over in different sections without the need to modify lots?

I agree pretty much with the answer from @Xeoncross for this one, but I like to view OOP from a more conceptual point of view: objects that collaborates throught message sends with the goal of modelling a subset of the reality (that is, your domain problem). I found it easier to think in terms of domain concepts instead of classes and interfaces (that's the way you use to *express* those domain concepts).

About the sample you posted, it's good to separate each branch of the conditional in its own method.

To learn why the previous is important, let´s take the following example: suppose there´s a bug in the media comments part of then code (and rest is working fine). For fixing it, you'll have to modify that part, potentially making changes that breaks already working code just because all belongs to the same method (remember, "If it ain't broke, don't fix it").

Follow @Darhazer advice and put each pice of logic in the class where it belongs. That way a class will only know about one and only one thing (MediaComments contains only the code that deals with media comments, ProfileComments does the same for profile comments, and so on). That will make it easy to locate, maintain and modify code related to a particular concept.

You can learn more about the reasons behind this decision reading about The Single Responsibility Principle [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [here](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf).

Also, I think you'll find interesting the "Replace Conditional with Polymorphism" section of Martin Fowler's book: [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) that explains the drawbacks of having a conditional statement like yours and gives you an object oriented technique to get rid of it.

Comment: +1 for the references, explaining the conceptual point of view and providing such beautiful summary :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends, but generally speaking you should try to separe chunk of code and do a simple task with each method. What will happen if you add another type of media in the future - you will end up adding "if elses" to this method.